# Counting max and min per row across columns and outputting associated column names

Tags: awk

I'm trying to count both max and min (except 0s) per row across columns and outputting associated column names.

I'm trying this:

```
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
     NR==1{print $1,$2,"ref","max","ref","min";
         for(i=3;i<=6;++i)BASES[i]=$(i);
     }
     NR>1{l=1;basemax=BASES[3];basemin=BASES[3]; max=$3; min=$3;
         for(i=4;i<=6;++i){
             if($i>max){basemax=BASES[i];max=$i;}
             else if($i==max){basemax=basemax","BASES[i];++l}
        }
         for(i=4;i<=6;++i){
             if($i<min && $i !=0){basemmin=BASES[i];mim=$i}
             else if($i==min){basemin=basemin","BASES[i];++l}
         }
         print $1,$2,basemax,max,basemin,min
     }
```

In a input that looks like this

```
chr     pos     C       T       A       G
NC_044998.1     3732    22      0       7       0
NC_044998.1     3733    22      0       0       0
NC_044998.1     3734    22      3       3       0
NC_044998.1     3735    22      0       0       3
NC_044998.1     3736    0       7       22      3
NC_044998.1     3737    0       0       0       25
NC_044998.1     3738    22      7       0       0
NC_044998.1     3739    7       3       22      25
NC_044998.1     3740    0       22      22      0
NC_044998.1     3741    22      0       0       0
```

The desired output is

```
chr          pos   ref  max  ref    min
NC_044998.1  3732  C    22   A      7
NC_044998.1  3733  C    22   C      22
NC_044998.1  3734  C    22   T,A    3
NC_044998.1  3735  C    22   G      3
NC_044998.1  3736  A    22   G      3
NC_044998.1  3737  G    25   G      25
NC_044998.1  3738  C    22   C      22
NC_044998.1  3739  G    25   C      7
NC_044998.1  3740  T,A  22   T,A    22
NC_044998.1  3741  C    22   C      22
```

But it outputs this instead

```
chr          pos   ref  max  ref    min
NC_044998.1  3732  C    22   C      22
NC_044998.1  3733  C    22   C      22
NC_044998.1  3734  C    22   C      22
NC_044998.1  3735  C    22   C      22
NC_044998.1  3736  A    22   C      0
NC_044998.1  3737  G    25   C,T,A  0
NC_044998.1  3738  C    22   C      22
NC_044998.1  3739  G    25   C      7
NC_044998.1  3740  T    22   C,A,G  0
NC_044998.1  3741  C    22   C      22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` script should work for you:

```sh
cat maxmin.awk

NR == 1 {
   for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i)
      hdr[i] = $i
   print $1, $2, "ref", "max", "ref", "min"
   next
}
{
   for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i) {
      max = ($i > max ? $i : max)
      min = ($i && (min == "" || $i < min) ? $i : min)
   }
   for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i) {
      if ($i == min)
         rmin = (rmin ? rmin "," : "") hdr[i]
      if ($i == max)
         rmax = (rmax ? rmax "," : "") hdr[i]
   }
   print $1, $2, rmax, max, rmin, min
   max = min = rmax = rmin = ""
}
```

And use it as:

```sh
awk -v b=3 -f maxmin.awk gg | column -t
chr          pos   ref  max  ref  min
NC_044998.1  3732  C    22   A    7
NC_044998.1  3733  C    22   C    22
NC_044998.1  3734  C    22   T,A  3
NC_044998.1  3735  C    22   G    3
NC_044998.1  3736  A    22   G    3
NC_044998.1  3737  G    25   G    25
NC_044998.1  3738  C    22   T    7
NC_044998.1  3739  G    25   T    3
NC_044998.1  3740  T,A  22   T,A  22
NC_044998.1  3741  C    22   C    22
```

`column -t` has been used for tabular output only.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using your solution, also because it was more intelligible to me!

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v startField="3" -v endField="6" '
BEGIN{ OFS="\t"; print "chr             pos     ref     max     ref     min"}
FNR==1{
  for(i=startField;i<=endField;i++){
    heading[i]=$i
  }
  next
}
{
  min=max2=maxInd2=minInd=max=maxInd=minAllInd=maxAllInd=maxAllInd2=""
  for(i=startField;i<=endField;i++){
    if($i!=0){
      minInd=(min>$i?i:(min==$i?minInd","i:(minInd!=""?minInd:i)))
      min=(min>$i?$i:(min!=""?min:$i))
    }
    maxInd=(max<$i?i:(max==$i?maxInd","i:(maxInd!=""?maxInd:i)))
    max=(max<$i?$i:(max!=""?max:$i))
  }
  for(i=startField+1;i<=endField;i++){
    maxInd2=(max2<$i?i:(max2==$i?maxInd2","i:(maxInd2!=""?maxInd2:i)))
    max2=(max2<$i?$i:(max2!=""?max2:$i))
  }
  num1=split(maxInd,arr1,",")
  num2=split(minInd,arr2,",")
  num3=split(maxInd2,arr3,",")
  if(num1>1){
    for(k=1;k<=num1;k++){
       maxAllInd = (maxAllInd?maxAllInd ",":"") heading[arr1[k]]
    }
  }
  else{
    maxAllInd = heading[maxInd]
  }
  if(num2>1){
    for(k=1;k<=num2;k++){
       minAllInd = (minAllInd?minAllInd ",":"") heading[arr2[k]]
    }
  }
  else{
    minAllInd = heading[minInd]
  }
  if(num3>1){
    for(k=1;k<=num3;k++){
       maxAllInd2 = (maxAllInd2?maxAllInd2 ",":"") heading[arr3[k]]
    }
  }
  else{
    maxAllInd2 = heading[maxInd2]
  }
  if(startField>1){
    NF=(startField-1)
      if(min !=0 ){
         print $0,maxAllInd,max,minAllInd,min
      }
      if(min == 0 && max2 != 0){
         print $0,maxAllInd,max,maxAllInd2,max2
      }
      if(min == 0 && max2 == 0){
         print $0,maxAllInd,max,maxAllInd,max
      }  
  }
  else{
      if(min !=0 ){
         print maxAllInd,max,minAllInd,min
      }
      if(min == 0 && max2 != 0){
         print maxAllInd,max,maxAllInd2,max2
      }
      if(min == 0 && max2 == 0){
         print maxAllInd,max,maxAllInd,max
      }       
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: I was testing this script. I think OP wants `NC_044998.1  3736  A    22   G      3`

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you sir, I have edited code, kindly do let me know if this looks Good now. cheers.

Comment: Yes it is producing correct output now ++

Answer (score 2):

- You have some typos in variable names such as `basemmin` and `mim`.
- If the count of `C` is `0`, the `min` value has no chance to be updated.
- You can combine the two `for` loops into one.
- The variable `l` is not used.

Then would you please try the following:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
NR==1 {
    print $1, $2, "ref", "max", "ref", "min"
    for (i = 3; i <= 6; i++) bases[i] = $i
}
NR>1 {
    basemax = bases[3]; basemin = bases[3]; max = $3; min = $3
    for (i = 4; i <= 6; i++) {
        if ($i > max) {basemax = bases[i]; max = $i}
        else if ($i == max) {basemax = basemax "," bases[i]}
        if ($i < min && $i != 0 || min == 0) {basemin = bases[i]; min = $i}
        else if ($i == min) {basemin = basemin "," bases[i]}
    }
    print $1, $2, basemax, max, basemin, min
}' input_file
```

Output:

```
chr     pos     ref     max     ref     min
NC_044998.1     3732    C       22      A       7
NC_044998.1     3733    C       22      C       22
NC_044998.1     3734    C       22      T,A     3
NC_044998.1     3735    C       22      G       3
NC_044998.1     3736    A       22      G       3
NC_044998.1     3737    G       25      G       25
NC_044998.1     3738    C       22      T       7
NC_044998.1     3739    G       25      T       3
NC_044998.1     3740    T,A     22      T,A     22
NC_044998.1     3741    C       22      C       22
```

Please note the output slightly differs from your desired output, which may contain typos.